# MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile - Ajax seems to be overwriting my ready function

Tags: c#, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so I have a page with some  elements and a few textarea that have display:none

Depending on the value of the select element the corresponding textarea becomes visible through a onchange event that sets `$('#comment').show()`

The page is a form with some validation and if the user pressed submit and validation did not pass the form redisplays with the same data and some errors messages..

Now the problem I am having is that although all the data displays the comment boxes are not there. I put some alerts in my javascript to see whats happening and I see that in THE END of my $(document).ready(function () the comment text areas are working and displaying fine but after that ajax seems to be re-displaying the entire page and the comment areas hide again.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      if ($('#Scope').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Scope').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ScopeComment");
      }

      if ($('#Schedule').val() == ("Yellow") || $('#Schedule').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ScheduleComment");
      }

      if ($('#Financial').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Financial').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("FinancialComment");
      }

      if ($('#Resource').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Resource').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ResourceComment");
      }

      if ($('#Risk').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Risk').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("RiskComment");
      }

      alert("hello"); -------> At this point I see the alert and behind it all correct text areas are shows, but right after I press "OK" Ajax re-displays the page and my comments all hide
  });

  function showComments(textID) {
      $('#' + textID).show();
  }
```

Does Ajax have it's own "ready" function that it calls after the jq mobile ready function?? or whats happening here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive which of these scenarios is a better match for your case, so I'll give you both of them.

**A. You are making an ajax call and manually returning and updating the data**

In this case you need to make the same call you made for the document.ready during the ajax callback after the data is put in its place. The document.ready event is only called the first time you load the page, and subsequent ajax requests that update these fields will not trigger that even. They have their own events such as `complete` and `success`.

**B. The entire page is being returned from the server.**

Instead of loading a whole new page, JQuery Mobile will make an ajax call to the get the content of the page and insert it into the DOM. This means that the document.ready function will only be called the first time you navigate to the website. What you want, is to bind to the the pageshow event. ex.

```
  $('#FormPage').live('pageshow', function () {

      if ($('#Scope').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Scope').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ScopeComment");
      }

      if ($('#Schedule').val() == ("Yellow") || $('#Schedule').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ScheduleComment");
      }

      if ($('#Financial').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Financial').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("FinancialComment");
      }

      if ($('#Resource').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Resource').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("ResourceComment");
      }

      if ($('#Risk').val() == "Yellow" || $('#Risk').val() == "Red") {
          showComments("RiskComment");
      }

      alert("hello"); -------> At this point I see the alert and behind it all correct text areas are shows, but right after I press "OK" Ajax re-displays the page and my comments all hide
 });
```

Comment: For answer B what should I be putting inside my #FormPage? The only place I have data-role="page" is in the main layout file and all the pages in the application are inside a <section data-role="content" > @RenderBody </section> in that main layout page.. The actual page with a form is simply a Html.BeginForm.. I tried putting that inside a <div role="page"> before but that made whatever is inside of it not display at all :S

Comment: Since you're just using document.ready right now, you can probably use $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function... This will bind it to all pages.